# How to add items to a ListBox from a class

Tags: c#, listbox

Basically I've got a TextBox, a buttom and a ListBox. 
I need to instantiate a contact in the Click buttom "Save" with the correct values from the Textbox, and add the instantiated contact into the ListBox.

So far I've wrote this code

```
public class Contact
{
    public void Name(string Fristname, string Lastname, string Phonenumber)
    {
        this.FristName = Fristname;
        this.LastName = Lastname;
        this.PhoneNumber = Phonenumber;

    }

    private string FristName {  get; set; }
    private string LastName { get; set; }
    private string PhoneNumber { get;  set; }
}
```

Comment: have you used and or executed a google search.. there are tons of working examples on how to populate a ListBox with values.. fix gour `FristName` variables it should be `FirstName` that's not a show stopper also where are you calling name ? you need to also create something like this `var contact = new List<Contact>()` then assign values to Firstname, LastName, etc

Comment: The easy things are to correct the spelling to Firstname and also make the properties public with a private setter.  As I read it, you seem to have ONE TextBox, both by say "a TextBox" and "the TextBox" so just how is the first name, last name, and phone number packed into the one TextBox.Text property?  That would go a long way to know how to split up one string into 3 individual strings.

Comment: Your Contact class lacks a constructor.  The Name method should have the 'void' removed and change 'Name' to 'Contact'.

Answer (score -2):

you need list items exmp:

```
List<Contact> listContact = new List<Contact>();

Contact c1 =new Contact("hunter","andone","212444444444");

listContact.add(c1);

ListBox2.items.addrange(listContact);
```